# facebook login code

Tags: c#, asp.net

In facebook..when u enter correct email address but incorrect passwd..they send u an email with an Instant login button..user can login using that instant login link only once..How did they implement this ? Where can i find its code? I mean how do they find out Instant Login link has been clicked only once ??

Any similar code over internet?

Comment: There's actually only **one** period at the end of a sentence.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of you getting "code", I think it's a matter of you implementing some sort of service. I've posted "what I would do in that situation", but I'm sure there's any number of ways to do this.

Comment: Yeah I kindof needed ideas only not code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement it as follows.

Create a table called "DirectLogin"

```
| GUID | UserID |
```

When the login attempt fails, create a new record in `DirectLogin` table.

Send the email with link

> http://example.com/DirectLogin?g=aaaa-ssss-dddd-ffff-gggg&e=user@example.com

When the user clicks the link, check if the GUID and email address match the record in the table.

If it does, log them in and delete the record

Comment: Facebook sends that email with Instant Login link only once..now how do I make sure email is sent ONLY on first wrong try ?

Comment: Well your code that sends the email would check the database first (only send if haven't attempted before)

Answer (score 1):

They probably store a indicator in the database: (**LoginAttempts**).

The user clicks the link, it increments the flag.

If they click it again, it checks the flag.

ASP.NET Membership Provider does a similar thing.